# Can we have multiple SNAT pools configured under a single VIP?

Tags: f5-big-ip

I have a little situation here, we have a VIP that contains 4 nodes present at two different locations (2 nodes in A location and other 2 nodes in B location), having different subnets (we have separate routes to reach each location). What we want to achieve here is to have two different SNAT pools under a single VIP, each dedicated for each subnet.

let us say, I have 2 nodes under subnet 10.0.0.0/24 and 2 nodes under 20.0.0.0/24 such that traffic uses
SNAT POOLs used: SNAT-1-->members--> 11.1.1.1 & 11.1.1.2 to reach nodes 10.0.0.0/24.
                 SNAT-2-->members--> 12.1.1.1 & 12.1.1.2 to reach nodes 20.0.0.0/24.

How can we have irule modified for this particular case?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward with an iRule:

```
when LB_SELECTED {
  if { [IP::addr [LB::server addr] equals 10.0.0.0/24] } {
    snatpool snat-1
  } else if { [IP::addr [LB::server addr] equals 10.0.0.0/24] } {
      snatpool snat-2
  }
}
```

Once the load balancing algorithm has determined the pool member, you can access that address with [LB::server](https://clouddocs.f5.com/api/irules/LB__server.html) in the [LB_SELECTED](https://clouddocs.f5.com/api/irules/LB_SELECTED.html) event, and once you compare it to your specified subnets, apply the [snatpool](https://clouddocs.f5.com/api/irules/snatpool.html) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Jason, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If the SNAT is in the same network as one of your SELF-IPS - it will autochoose the SNAT address correctly.   Create a group of SNAT addresses one snat in the network for each SELF-IP - and put that in a SNAT group - assign that group to the VIP.   The F5 will autoselect the SNAT based on the self-ip used to get to your pool member (which means you have to have a route to each destination which you said you do have)

Comment: didn't tell the user that they shall do something, SHOW the way how they can resolve that, in a complete one